# $injector:unpr Unknown provider on loopback

Tags: mysql, angularjs, loopback

So, i've searched for an answer to this problem and the solutions presented on the other questions won't work. To be honest i'm already on the testing every possibility.

I have a loopback app with angular and connected to mySQL database. 
The explorer from loopback works and i can get and post data to the db.

The problem comes when i try to retrieve it with angularjs on a controller. 
what i have is this:

app.js:

```
angular
.module('app', [
  'ui.router',
  'lbServices'
])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider,
  $urlRouterProvider) {
 $stateProvider
  .state('weddings', {
    url: '',
    templateUrl: 'views/Weddings.html',
    controller: 'WeddingsController',
  })
  .state('Calendar', {
    url: '/Calendar',
    templateUrl: 'views/Calendar.html',
    controller: 'CalendarController',
  });
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('weddings');
}]);
```

Weddings.js:

```
angular.module('app').controller('WeddingsController', ['$scope', '$state', 
'$http', 'weddings', function($scope, $state, $http, weddings) {
  $scope.temp = [];
  function getWeddings() {
      weddings.find().$promise
        .then(function(results) {
          $scope.temp = results;
        }, 
        function(err) {
          $scope.requestsError = err.statusText;
        }
    );
  }
  getWeddings();
}]);
```

That gives me : [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: weddingsProvider <- weddings <- WeddingsController

if someone can spot something wrong please enlighten me.

Ps: the injections might be too much, im just putting them all out there to see if works :/

Comment: Angular doesn't know about the wedding service, register it with the module  before using it. Add mode details to track down the issue.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't know? it's just a model , i don't have a service.

Comment: weddings is added as a dependency to the WeddingsController, but angular unaware of the existence of weddings.

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm really confused . so where do i make him aware?

Comment: Read about dependency injection  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: Yeah, i'm just dumb . After you mentioned services i went to check and i didn't update my angular-loopback service file after inserting the new models . Thanks anyway